# Creating multiple new columns using one function in Pandas

Tags: function, dataframe, pandas

I know that this is probably very simple but I have been trying to work this out for a while, and I need it for quite a few functions.

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns, both with share price data.

I would like to compute 2 new columns in a new dataframe called 'returns', with each column named as the same as in the first (i.e. 'AAPL' and 'GOOG').

I use this procedure to get the original data and create the 'data' dataframe:

```
names = ['AAPL', 'GOOG']

def get_data(stock, start, end):
    return web.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)['Adj Close']

data = pd.DataFrame({n: get_data(n, '1/1/2009', '6/1/2012') for n in names})
```

I know that the returns could be generate using (from the pandas library):

```
returns = pd.DataFrame(index=data.index)
returns['*COLUMN A*'] = data['*COLUMN A*'].pct_change()
```

However I am guessing that I need to use some sort of loop to iterate over either 'names' or the columns but I cannot get anything to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am sorry if I have been rather vague, but this is my first question and I have searched for 30 minutes through the forum :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pct_change on the entire df

```
In [15]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(20,size=20).reshape(10,2),
    columns=['AAPL','GOOG'],index=date_range('20130101',periods=10))+50

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
            AAPL  GOOG
2013-01-01    53    54
2013-01-02    66    64
2013-01-03    50    59
2013-01-04    53    57
2013-01-05    67    65
2013-01-06    61    55
2013-01-07    68    52
2013-01-08    64    65
2013-01-09    62    62
2013-01-10    66    50

In [17]: 100*df.pct_change()
Out[17]: 
                 AAPL       GOOG
2013-01-01        NaN        NaN
2013-01-02  24.528302  18.518519
2013-01-03 -24.242424  -7.812500
2013-01-04   6.000000  -3.389831
2013-01-05  26.415094  14.035088
2013-01-06  -8.955224 -15.384615
2013-01-07  11.475410  -5.454545
2013-01-08  -5.882353  25.000000
2013-01-09  -3.125000  -4.615385
2013-01-10   6.451613 -19.354839
```

Comment: ah Voila, perfect! I knew I was likely overcomplicating it. Thank you very much!